# Call Directory Extension invisible for app

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I tried to use Call Directory Extension in my App. Unfortunately every time I call to phone from declared earlier number I don't get any label ID or information that extension isn't working. I only can accept permissions from settings > block and identify calls, but after that I don't get nothing. It looks like phone number isn't available. I just put my number into *addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbers* function in *CallDirectoryHandler* everything else I just leave as it was. Is there something I should do to make this extension work? I make research on google but doesn't find anything that would make this application extension works.

```
import Foundation
import CallKit

class CallDirectoryHandler: CXCallDirectoryProvider {

    override func beginRequest(with context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {
        context.delegate = self
        if context.isIncremental {
            addOrRemoveIncrementalBlockingPhoneNumbers(to: context)

            addOrRemoveIncrementalIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to: context)
        } else {
            addAllBlockingPhoneNumbers(to: context)

            addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to: context)
        }

        context.completeRequest()
    }

    private func addAllBlockingPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {

        let allPhoneNumbers: [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber] = [ 1_408_555_5555, 1_800_555_5555 ]
        for phoneNumber in allPhoneNumbers {
            context.addBlockingEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumber)
        }
    }

    private func addOrRemoveIncrementalBlockingPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {

        let phoneNumbersToAdd: [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber] = [ 1_408_555_1234 ]
        for phoneNumber in phoneNumbersToAdd {
            context.addBlockingEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumber)
        }

        let phoneNumbersToRemove: [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber] = [ 1_800_555_5555 ]
        for phoneNumber in phoneNumbersToRemove {
            context.removeBlockingEntry(withPhoneNumber: phoneNumber)
        }
    }

    private func addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {

        let allPhoneNumbers: [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber] = [ 48791111222, 1_888_555_5555 ]
        let labels = [ "Telemarketer", "Local business" ]

        for (phoneNumber, label) in zip(allPhoneNumbers, labels) {
            context.addIdentificationEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumber, label: label)
        }
    }

    private func addOrRemoveIncrementalIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {
        let phoneNumbersToAdd: [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber] = [ 1_408_555_5678 ]
        let labelsToAdd = [ "New local business" ]

        for (phoneNumber, label) in zip(phoneNumbersToAdd, labelsToAdd) {
            context.addIdentificationEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumber, label: label)
        }

        let phoneNumbersToRemove: [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber] = [ 1_888_555_5555 ]

        for phoneNumber in phoneNumbersToRemove {
            context.removeIdentificationEntry(withPhoneNumber: phoneNumber)
        }
    }

}

extension CallDirectoryHandler: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContextDelegate {

    func requestFailed(for extensionContext: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext, withError error: Error) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Is your already associated with with a contact in your phone?  The numbers you add must be in ascending order, so the array of numbers you have in your question is incorrect. The number starting with "4"would need to come second.

Comment: @Paulw11 To use this Extension should I create some function to store numbers in contacts on phone? Or Should I add maybe "+" to directional to make it works? I change the order of this two numbers and nothing changed. Still doesn't work at all.

Comment: No, I was just checking that you didn't have the number on a contact since that will override the extension. The "+"at the start of the number is implied since it is an integer, not a string.

Comment: I suggest you put a print of the error in the `failed` delegate method, but you will need to attach the debugger to your extension project in order to see any print output; you need to tell the debugger to attach to your directory extension by name and then launch it by toggling call identification on/off